# word count, form size, displayed things size in html

Tags: python, html, count

Is there a library in python to count the size of the thing displayed on html ?

exemple :

```
<a href="">titi</a>
```

here only titi count and is 4

on a form the size of the things displayed ?

```
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="40" name="name">
```

here it's ten

or i have to do a parsing ?

Regards

Bussiere

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the HTML.

Use a library like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the values and attributes as you require, and then you can identify the numeric value of a form attribute or count the length of text within a tag.

Per the documentation linked, if you ran the HTML through Beautiful Soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# html_doc is presumed to already contain the contents of the HTML document
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
```

You could then find the length of the document title, for example

```
print "Document title length: %s" % len(soup.title.string)
```

Or the text for each link

```
doc_links = soup.find_all('a')
link_text_length = [len(link.string) for link in
        doc_links if len(link.string) > 40]
total_long_links = len(link_text_length)
print "%s links are too long in the document" % total_long_links
```